# How to subset a vector by indices given in another vector?

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have two vectors of equal length, one containing numeric values (`num_vec`), the other containing only zeros and ones (`bool_vec`). My goal is to keep all values in `num_vec` with indices that correspond to ones in `bool_vec`. Here is an example:

```
num_vec <- c(1:5)
bool_vec <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
```

The  output should be:

```
> output
[1] 3 5
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

We just need to convert the binary to logical with `as.logical` so that 1 converts to TRUE and 0 to FALSE.  Then use that index to subset the vector

```
num_vec[as.logical(bool_vec)]
```